# How to dynamically initialize array in "object oriented" C?

Tags: c, oop, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the code below, how and where do I dynamically initialize an array that is in the Class struct? For example, if I made it double *var instead, where does the malloc statement go?

myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

struct Class;

struct Class *new_class();
void class_function(struct Class*,double);

#endif
```

myclass.c

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Class {
    double var;
};

struct Class *new_class()
{
    return (struct Class *)malloc(sizeof(struct Class));
}

void class_function(struct Class *inst, double num)
{
    inst->var = num;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "myclass.h"

int main()
{
    struct Class *c1 = new_class();
    class_function(c1,0.15);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried modifying the new_class function to something like

```
struct Class *new_class(int len)
{
    Class c1 = (struct Class *)malloc(sizeof(struct Class));
    c1.var = (double)malloc(len*sizeof(double));
    return c1;
}
```

with no luck. Do I need to create a separate function for allocation? What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, first change the `struct` definition to

```
struct Class 
{
    double *var;
    size_t  len;
};
```

and then

```
struct Class *new_class(int len)
{
    struct Class *c1;
    c1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Class));
    if (c1 == NULL)
        return NULL;
    c1->var = malloc(len * sizeof(double));
    if (c1->var == NULL)
    {
        free(c1);
        return NULL;
    }
    c1->len = len;

    return c1;
}
```

your `class_function()` should be check if the pointer is `NULL`, believe me, you will thank me in this future for this

```
void set_class_value(struct Class *inst, int index, double num)
{
    if ((inst == NULL) || (inst->var == NULL) || (index < 0) || (index >= inst->len))
        return;
    inst->var[index] = num;
}
```

you can also have

```
double get_class_value(struct Class *inst, int index)
{
    if ((inst == NULL) || (inst->var == NULL) || (index < 0) || (index >= inst->len))
        return 0.0; /* or any value that would indicate failure */
    return inst->var[index];
}
```

you must have a function to release resources when you finish

```
void free_class(struct Class *klass)
{
    if (klass == NULL)
        return;
    free(klass->var);
    free(klass);
}
```

And now `main()`

```
int main()
{
    struct Class *c1;
    c1 = new_class(5);
    if (c1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Memory exhausted\n");
        return -1;
    }
    set_class_value(c1, 0, 0.15);
    printf("%f\n", get_class_value(c1, 0));

    free_class(c1);
    return 0;
}
```

this I think should help, though not much explanation, I think the code speaks by itself.

Note that I added a `len` field to the struct, because otherwise it wouldn't make sense to have a `struct` to store an array of `double`, so by knowing the size of the number of elements in the array you can prevent problems, you should also learn about opaque types and how to hide the structure definition from the structure users, so you force a safe usage.

Comment: In `new_class`, you should also check the 2nd malloc return, then `free(c1)` and `return NULL;` if it failed.  If its not done in `new_class()` it needs to be done outside of `new_class` and no one will ever remember to do that.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland not necessarily because after all it will be always possible to check for the `var` member, though your solution implies that failure to `malloc` at any stage means that the `struct` cannot be allocated, so I will use it, good point.

Comment: Thanks. I feel stupid now for trying to return the struct when the return value for the function is clearly a pointer to it.

Comment: @user1801359 Yes it is, and please take into account all the checks that I added in my code, trust me, you will be very happy to get used to writing programs like this, it prevents so many silly errors, but so many...